# Aggregation performance on large collection in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework

I have a large collection in mongodb. It has around 70-80 million documents in that collection.
But when i run aggregation pipeline on it, it takes almost 5 minutes to return the results.
Is there any way we can reduce the aggregation result time ??

I cant get any relevant solution to reduce the time for aggregation pipeline.

Below is the sample document.

```
   {
  "data": {
    "_id": "5e557779ed588826d84cef27",
    "meter_id": "1001",
    "date": "2017-10-31T18:52:00.000Z",
    "parameter_name": "hvac",
    "voltage": {
      "unit": "V",
      "Voltage": 0
    },
    "current": {
      "unit": "AMP",
      "Current": 0
    },
    "powerFactor": {
      "unit": "phi",
      "PowerFactor": 0
    },
    "angle": {
      "unit": "degree"
    },
    "activePower": {
      "unit": "kwh"
    },
    "reactivePower": {
      "unit": "kwh"
    },
    "apparentPower": {
      "unit": "kwh",
      "ApparentPower": 0
    },
    "frequency": {
      "unit": "hz",
      "Frequency": 0
    },
    "thd": {
      "unit": "percentage"
    },
    "energy": {
      "unit": "J",
      "Energy": 0
    },
    "power": {
      "unit": "watt",
      "Power": 0
    },
    "__v": 0
  }
}
```

And below is the aggregation pipeline i am using

```
MeterData.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
        $expr: {
            $and: [
                 {$gt: ["$date", checkDate] },
                { $lt: ["$date", moment(checkDate).add(1, 'years')._d] },
              ]
        }

    }
},
{

  $group: {
    _id: {  
      day: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m", date: "$date" } },
      meter: '$meter_id'

  },
  totalEnergy: { $sum: { $toDouble: "$energy.Energy" } },
  }
},
{
    $project: {
        meter_id: '$_id.meter',
        month: '$_id.day',
        totalEnergy: '$totalEnergy',
                _id: 0
    }
},
{
    $sort: { month: 1 }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to add your aggregation query to the question, and sample documents.

Comment: @SuleymanSah I have added the sample document and the query for the aggregation which i am using.

Comment: Can you please add the sample document in json format?

Comment: @SuleymanSah Added the document in the json format.

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives to this:

1. You can create indices on the fields which you specifically need to query on. This is the first recommended approach. [Link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/)
2. Create summary collections on top of your existing collection containing the references. So essentially this means that you have a key which uniquely identifies a record in your current collection and then create a summary collection on top which houses these references. This will also lead to a change in the user frontend where you can portray the results as multiple steps based on what you retrieve. It's always a nice tradeoff to have for a UX vs query-time performance with big data.